# How Magento add the shipping amount in orders while creating in backend

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, orders, shipping-methods, backend

Recently i am facing one issue **while creating order in back end**

In backend while creating new order on choosing shipping method it's adding shipping amount in totals.

**But on submit the order it's not showing up in order details page.**

I tried checking with order info.

`$_order->getShippingDescription();` (showing Table Rate as i selected)

`$_order->getShippingAmount();` (Showing 0.00 not expected)

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php
```

I saw core files also the above file used to set shipping_method name. No where i found the shipping amount is being set.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to see this file: `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php`

Have you set up any 'Catalog Price Rules' that returns free shipping in some situations?

Comment: I found the issue. Some place in phtml i saw the static code as reset_shipping was value set to 1  that was using in this core files  /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php
 
This was the problem. :(